# Why does my node disappear immediately after a click event with Sigmajs/NEO4J?

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I'm trying to retrieve a node with NEO4J request (cypher) with an input search string. When I click on my button search the function drawGraph() is launch. I see the node as a result in my graph container but it disappear immediately.

in my html code a have the click event:

```
<form>
<input id="inputsearch" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<button id="buttonsearch" onclick="drawGraph(inputsearch.value)" 
type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

My code below :

```
    // Neo4j config object
var neo4jConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:7474', user: 'neo4j', password: 
'neo4j' };        
var inputsearch= document.getElementById('inputsearch');
var buttonSearch=document.getElementById('buttonsearch');
//buttonSearch.addEventListener('click', drawGraph(inputsearch.value));   


// function to apply style rules
function applyStyle(s) {
// Node style
s.graph.nodes().forEach(function (node){

          if (node.neo4j_labels[0] === "Movie"){
            node.label = node.neo4j_data['movie'];
            node.color = '#8367C7';
            node.size = 16;
            node.type = "star";
          }
          else if (node.neo4j_labels[0] === "Person"){
            node.label = node.neo4j_data['person'];
            node.type = "diamond";
            node.color = '#23CE6B';
            node.size = 12;
          }

});
 // Edge style
 s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
  e.originalColor = e.color;
  e.type = "curvedArrow";
  e.size=2;
 });

var dragListener = new sigma.plugins.dragNodes(s, s.renderers[0]);

CustomShapes.init(s);
s.refresh();
}


// init sigma
s = new sigma({
renderer: {
  container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
  type: 'canvas'
}
});


 CustomShapes.init(s);
 s.refresh();  

 s.bind("doubleClickNode", function(e) {
 var node = e.data.node;
 var query = 'MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) WHERE id(n)=' + node.id+ ' RETURN n,r,m';


  sigma.neo4j.cypher(
  neo4jConfig,
  query,
  function(graph) {
    // adding node if not existing
    graph.nodes.forEach(function (node){
        if(s.graph.nodes(node.id) === undefined) {
        s.graph.addNode(node);
      }
    });
    // adding edge if not existing
    graph.edges.forEach(function (edge){
        if(s.graph.edges(edge.id) === undefined) {
        s.graph.addEdge(edge);
      }
    });

   // apply style
    applyStyle(s);
  }
);

});

// display cypher query
sigma.neo4j.cypher(
neo4jConfig,
'MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m LIMIT 1',
s,
applyStyle
);


function drawGraph(inputsearch){

 sigma.neo4j.cypher(neo4jConfig,
 'match (n:Person)-[r]->(m) where n.nom =~ "(?i).*' + inputsearch + '.*" 
 return n LIMIT 1;',
 s,
 applyStyle)

};    

CustomShapes.init(s);
s.refresh();
```

can anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: I have verified and there is no error in the console. Perhaps i need to use a callback function, but i don't know how to use it.